# Extracting the full querystring from a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string

Using ASP.NET MVC, I have the following URL returned from a commeweb payment gateway:

```
http://localhost/ASP_VPC_3Party_DR?&vpc_AVSResultCode=Unsupported&vpc_AcqAVSRe
spCode=Unsupported&vpc_AcqCSCRespCode=Unsupported&vpc_AcqResponseCode=00&vpc_
Amount=100&vpc_AuthorizeId=000281&vpc_BatchNo=1&vpc_CSCRequestCode=N&vpc_CSCRe
sultCode=Unsupported&vpc_Card=AE&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en_AU&vpc_MerchTxn
Ref=123&vpc_Merchant=TESTANDREWK&vpc_Message=Approved&vpc_OrderInfo=VPC+Exam
ple&vpc_ReceiptNo=030821000281&vpc_SecureHash=6EB600780CAA5B1C81BF3AF249E4B85
3&vpc_TransactionNo=281&vpc_TxnResponseCode=0&vpc_Version=1
```

I need to store this:

```
&vpc_AVSResultCode=Unsupported&vpc_AcqAVSRe
spCode=Unsupported&vpc_AcqCSCRespCode=Unsupported&vpc_AcqResponseCode=00&vpc_
Amount=100&vpc_AuthorizeId=000281&vpc_BatchNo=1&vpc_CSCRequestCode=N&vpc_CSCRe
sultCode=Unsupported&vpc_Card=AE&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en_AU&vpc_MerchTxn
Ref=123&vpc_Merchant=TESTANDREWK&vpc_Message=Approved&vpc_OrderInfo=VPC+Exam
ple&vpc_ReceiptNo=030821000281&vpc_SecureHash=6EB600780CAA5B1C81BF3AF249E4B85
3&vpc_TransactionNo=281&vpc_TxnResponseCode=0&vpc_Version=1
```

... as a single variable in my database

Comment: `?&` looks strange to me.

Comment: You ask about `full url` , but what you need is the `query_string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask about full url , but what you need is the query_string.

Full url: `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

Query string: `Request.Url.Query`

Answer (score 0):

You can get full url.

Request.Url.PathAndQuery

then parse string str.Substring(str.IndexOf('&'))

it gets whole string from starting of &